# How can I display a modal dialog in my Windows Mobile app?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, smartphone

I wanted to know how I can display a modal dialog in one of my forms in a windows mobile application. I am getting the user inputs in a form and in case a validation fails, I want to display a dialog to the user telling them so (with just an OK button).

So far, the only thing related to dialogs I found in the framework was the DialogResult class.

I am developing for Windows Smart phone using the Windows Mobile 6 Standard SDK.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Compact Framework supports [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx), which pops up a modal message. If all you need to do is display some text and wait for an OK, that works fine.